# problemas con un where y el and

Tags: firebird

Tengo este procedimiento y así como está me funciona bien pero, quiero modificarla porque en la suma total me hace la suma de todos los registros y no los del rango de una fecha específica, así que escribí esto:

```
and *****a.fecha >= :fechainicio or a.fecha <=  :fechafin ),*****


begin
if (quincena = '1') then
   dia='1';
   if (quincena = '2') then
   dia='16';
ftdfecha =(select cast (:anno||'-'||:mes||'-'||:dia as date) from rdb$database);

  fechainicio = ftdfecha;
  fechafin = dateadd(15 day to fechainicio);
for select  a.codigoproveedor,
(SELECT b.nombreproveedor FROM proveedores b
WHERE a.codigoproveedor = b.codigoproveedor and *****where a.fecha >= :fechainicio or a.fecha <=  :fechafin),*****
sum (a.montototal)
FROM produccion a
where (a.fecha >= :fechainicio or a.fecha <=  :fechafin)
group by a.codigoproveedor
into :codigoproved,:nombreproved,:producciones

do begin

suspend;
end
end
```

y me da este error el Firebird:

```
Can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\WINDOWS\firebird.msg not found.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).
```

¿Me pueden decir cómo solucionarlo o escribirme el código de manera correcta?
mil gracias

Comment: Por favor, revisa tu pregunta e intenta formatear el código correctamente para que veamos que has hecho.

Comment: Cambia `group by a.codigoproveedor` por  `b.nombreproveedor`

Answer (score 0):

En SQL Server he tenido problemas similares y por lo que he visto pudieras optar por 2 posibles soluciones:

1. Agregarle el campo `b.nombreproveedor` en la parte del `group by`
2. En el `select` hacer una subconsulta buscando a partir del campo `a.codigoproveedor` que te devuelva el `b.nombreproveedor`.

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate de colocar los campos al `group by`. Al parecer debes colocar `b.nombreproveedor`.

Hablando específicamente de la consulta SQL, veo que puede ser posible utilizar una `JOIN` en lugar de una subconsulta.

Pero desconozco si Firebird permite esa instrucción.